# How to get JavaFx suggestions like <Label>, <Button>... in an fxml file? Because they are inaccessible to me

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader, java-12

I'm currently in JavaFX training and it turns out I need an FXML file, all works perfectly:

1. I can create the FXML file
2. I can define my rootPane
3. But when I want to add elements like `<Label>`, `<Button>`... these are not made available to me.

**JAVA version:** 12.0.2

**IDE :** Eclipse

**Eclipse pluggin :** e(fx)clipse

The images below will speak for themselves:

[image: problem to solve image] => [image: desired solution]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some import statements, such as `<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>`

Comment: Yes, but I can't do an import dynamically, like we do so easily with java => Declare our need, and Eclipse takes care of importing the necessary.

Comment: I suggest you try `<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>`. I am not sure about it, but it is worth trying.